# Determining Day Of Week For Datetime in SPARQL

Tags: datetime, sparql

I have a graph I am trying to filter for a report by day of week.  For instance, I wish to find all the instances where they occurred on a Tuesday.  Is there a way to either format the datetime field into day of week or filter by day of week directly on the datetime field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also determine the day of week in standard SPARQL if you provided a bit of background knowledge. The query needs a reference date preceding your dates and the day of week at this date.

```
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?date ?dayName
WHERE {
  # Sample dates
  VALUES ?date {
    "1961-08-04"^^xsd:date
    "1986-04-03"^^xsd:date
  }
  # Compute days since a reference date
  # This works in Virtuoso, which returns the difference in days.
  # For example, Fuseki returns xsd:duration instead.
  BIND (?date - "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date AS ?days)
  # Compute modulo by 7 without a modulo operator
  BIND (floor(?days - (7 * floor(?days/7))) AS ?mod)
  VALUES (?mod ?dayName) {
         (0    "Monday") # 1900-01-01 was Monday
         (6    "Tuesday")
         (5    "Wednesday")
         (4    "Thursday")
         (3    "Friday")
         (2    "Saturday")
         (1    "Sunday")
  }
}
```

Comment: Very handy - and have ended up using this since it's standard SPARQL :)

Comment: It relies on standard syntax, but also on specific semantics. As noted in the query comment, the date difference returns a number of days in Virtuoso, but `xsd:duration` in Fuseki (and implementations in other RDF stores may differ). This makes the query specific to Virtuoso and similarly behaving RDF stores.

Comment: @JindřichMynarz I think Virtuoso semantics are non-standard here.
Also, you can do arithmetics with `xsd:duration`, e.g. `(AVG(?age) / xsd:dayTimeDuration("P365D") AS ?avgAge)`

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius - It should be noted that your calculation here ignores leap years. This may not matter in many cases, but there are also many cases where it would be important.

Answer (score 5):

SPARQL does not have a 'day of week' function built-in, however, most programming languages have built-in support for retrieving day of week from a given calendar/date object. For example, using Java and RDF4J, you could simply retrieve the dateTime literal (represented as a `Literal` object with `xsd:dateTime` datatype), convert to a Java calendar object, and then retrieve the weekday:

```java
Literal value = ... ; // the RDF4J literal value from your query result
Calendar calendar = value.calendarValue().toGregorianCalendar(); 
int weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

In addition, most SPARQL engines offer the option of adding custom functions.

So you can either just retrieve the dateTime and post-process the result to get the day of the week, or you can actually create a custom function and add it to your SPARQL engine. Here's a tutorial on [how to add a custom function to SPARQL using Sesame/RDF4J](http://www.rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/creating-custom-sparql-functions/).

Comment: Thanks Jeen, That's what I was thinking but wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Note that this "programming language" option does take the filtration outside of the database engine, which may massively increase your processing time as well as the volume of transmitted data. That may be a worthwhile tradeoff in your immediate case, but it often won't be.

Answer (score 4):

SPARQL doesn't have a name-of-day function, but if your SPARQL endpoint is a [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) instance, you can leverage its SQL functions.  Here's a [query you can run against DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qxt=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%20bif%3Adayname%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%20AS%20%20%3Fdayname%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FBarack_Obama%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthDate%3E%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
SELECT
                                   ?birthdate 
    ( bif:dayname(?birthdate)  AS  ?dayname )
WHERE
   {  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>
         <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate>  ?birthdate 
   }
```

-- which will get [Barack Obama's birthdate and day](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%20bif%3Adayname%28%3Fbirthdate%29%20%20AS%20%20%3Fdayname%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FBarack_Obama%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FbirthDate%3E%20%20%3Fbirthdate%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
birthdate    dayname
1961-08-04   Friday
```

I'm thinking it was more the lack of such a function that was blocking you, than not knowing how to build your SPARQL `FILTER`?

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)

Comment: Indeed - and since I'm using Virtuoso this is also quite helpful!  I'm deep diving into SPARQL after being a long time SQL user, so things I'm used to being able to do in SQL/code I'm starting to figure out in SPARQL.

Comment: If Virtuoso would implement specs properly, no extension function would be necessary.

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius - We would appreciate it if you could log [an issue against the Virtuoso project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues), which makes plain the departure from spec you're suggesting we have. Links here and/or there to the specific SPARQL and XML Schema spec sections you're trying to highlight would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I used Jindrich's solution and tried to refactor it using `xsd:duration` arithmetics (which follows the SPARQL and XPath specs, unlike Virtuoso):

```
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?date ?dayName
WHERE {
  # Sample dates
  VALUES ?date {
    "1961-08-04"^^xsd:date
    "1986-04-03"^^xsd:date
  }
  BIND (xsd:date(?date) - "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date AS ?days)
  BIND (?days - (xsd:dayTimeDuration("P7D") * floor(?days / xsd:dayTimeDuration("P7D"))) AS ?mod)
  BIND (str(?mod) AS ?modStr)
  VALUES (?modStr ?dayName) {
         ("PT0S"   "Monday") # 1900-01-01 was Monday
         ("P1D"    "Tuesday")
         ("P2D"    "Wednesday")
         ("P3D"    "Thursday")
         ("P4D"    "Friday")
         ("P5D"    "Saturday")
         ("P6D"    "Sunday")
  }
}
```

I ran the query on [Dydra](https://dydra.com) and I get the right results for the sample dates (Friday and Thursday), but haven't tested further than that.

Comment: Virtuoso issue: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/843

Answer (score 0):

The solution also works with Virtuoso as per this [SPARQL Results Page Link](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fdate%20%3FdayName%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23%20Sample%20dates%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fdate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221961-08-04%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221986-04-03%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28xsd%3Adate%28%3Fdate%29%20-%20%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20AS%20%3Fdays%29%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%3Fdays%20-%20%28xsd%3AdayTimeDuration%28%22P7D%22%29%20*%20floor%28%3Fdays%20%2F%20xsd%3AdayTimeDuration%28%22P7D%22%29%29%29%20AS%20%3Fmod%29%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28str%28%3Fmod%29%20AS%20%3FmodStr%29%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3FmodStr%20%3FdayName%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22PT0S%22%20%20%20%22Monday%22%29%20%23%201900-01-01%20was%20Monday%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P1D%22%20%20%20%20%22Tuesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P2D%22%20%20%20%20%22Wednesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P3D%22%20%20%20%20%22Thursday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P4D%22%20%20%20%20%22Friday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P5D%22%20%20%20%20%22Saturday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P6D%22%20%20%20%20%22Sunday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000).

Comment: Ooops!  That solution is incorrect, so we have something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the initial solution works re. Virtuoso as per this [SPARQL Results Page](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fdate%20%3FdayName%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23%20Sample%20dates%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fdate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221961-08-04%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221986-04-03%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%23%20Compute%20days%20since%20a%20reference%20date%0D%0A%20%20%23%20This%20works%20in%20Virtuoso%2C%20which%20returns%20the%20difference%20in%20days.%0D%0A%20%20%23%20For%20example%2C%20Fuseki%20returns%20xsd%3Aduration%20instead.%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28%3Fdate%20-%20%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20AS%20%3Fdays%29%0D%0A%20%20%23%20Compute%20modulo%20by%207%20without%20a%20modulo%20operator%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28floor%28%3Fdays%20-%20%287%20*%20floor%28%3Fdays%2F7%29%29%29%20AS%20%3Fmod%29%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fmod%20%3FdayName%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%280%20%20%20%20%22Monday%22%29%20%23%201900-01-01%20was%20Monday%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%286%20%20%20%20%22Tuesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%285%20%20%20%20%22Wednesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%284%20%20%20%20%22Thursday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%283%20%20%20%20%22Friday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%282%20%20%20%20%22Saturday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%281%20%20%20%20%22Sunday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%201&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000).

Basically, the original response:

```
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?date ?dayName
WHERE {
  # Sample dates
  VALUES ?date {
    "1961-08-04"^^xsd:date
    "1986-04-03"^^xsd:date
  }
  # Compute days since a reference date
  # This works in Virtuoso, which returns the difference in days.
  # For example, Fuseki returns xsd:duration instead.
  BIND (?date - "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date AS ?days)
  # Compute modulo by 7 without a modulo operator
  BIND (floor(?days - (7 * floor(?days/7))) AS ?mod)
  VALUES (?mod ?dayName) {
         (0    "Monday") # 1900-01-01 was Monday
         (6    "Tuesday")
         (5    "Wednesday")
         (4    "Thursday")
         (3    "Friday")
         (2    "Saturday")
         (1    "Sunday")
  }
}

# Catch occurrence of any cartesian product that can trick the human eye by adding ORDER BY CLAUSE 

ORDER BY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revision that produces the correct solution by applying a pragma for disabling the query optimizer.

```
DEFINE sql:disable-optimizations 16
PREFIX xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?date ?dayName
WHERE {
  # Sample dates
  VALUES ?date {
    "1961-08-04"^^xsd:date
    "1986-04-03"^^xsd:date
  }
  BIND (xsd:date(?date) - "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date AS ?days)
  BIND (bif:mod (?days, xsd:dayTimeDuration("P7D")) AS ?mod)
  VALUES (?mod ?dayName) {
         ("PT0S"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration "Monday") # 1900-01-01 was Monday
         ("P1D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Tuesday")
         ("P2D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Wednesday")
         ("P3D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Thursday")
         ("P4D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Friday")
         ("P5D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Saturday")
         ("P6D"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration    "Sunday")
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC (?date)
```

[SPARQL Query Results Page](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=define%20sql%3Adisable-optimizations%2016%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fdate%20%3FdayName%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23%20Sample%20dates%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fdate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221961-08-04%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221986-04-03%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28xsd%3Adate%28%3Fdate%29%20-%20%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3Adate%20AS%20%3Fdays%29%0D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28bif%3Amod%20%28%3Fdays%2C%20xsd%3AdayTimeDuration%28%22P7D%22%29%29%20AS%20%3Fmod%29%0D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fmod%20%3FdayName%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22PT0S%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%22Monday%22%29%20%23%201900-01-01%20was%20Monday%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P1D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Tuesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P2D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Wednesday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P3D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Thursday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P4D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Friday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P5D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Saturday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%22P6D%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdayTimeDuration%20%20%20%20%22Sunday%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%20%28%3Fdate%29&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000&debug=on)

Comment: The bug is still not fixed though :)
https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/843