# Idea to create a-day-of-a-week historical calendar (thousands of years) in RDF

Tags: csv, date, rdf, dayofweek, gregorian-calendar

I need your good ideas. I am considering to create a big dataset for historical calendar in RDF. For example, one day of 1860 in RDF/XML would simply look like (just an ISO date with the day of a week):

```
<abc:date rdf:about="https://example.com/date/1860-05-08">
   <abc:dayOfWeek>Tuesday</abc:dayOfWeek>
</abc:date>
```

Apparently, I need to calculate the day of the week, out of YYYY-MM-DD. In this way, I would like to generate this data for c365 days for each year. The overall scope would be around 4000 years (2000 BC - Present), thus including pre- Gregorian calendar. If that's a bit too ambitious, for now, 1800 onward is enough.

What would be a good way to achieve this? Is there a freely available database (CSV etc) out of which I could generate this kind of data automatically?

(Potentially, it would be excellent, if additional information can be added:

```
<abc:date rdf:about="https://example.com/date/1860-05-08">
   <abc:dayOfWeek>Tuesday</abc:dayOfWeek>
   <abc:location rdf:about="https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1741">
      <abc:sunRise>4:29AM</abc:sunRise>
      <abc:sunSet>7:23PM</abc:sunSet>
   </abc:location>
</abc:date>
```

See this example here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+day+of+the+week+was+1860-05-08)

Thank you for your ideas in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining Day Of Week For Datetime in SPARQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729208/determining-day-of-week-for-datetime-in-sparql)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This Q&A is interesting and useful when data is already available, but does not answer my question. My question is about generating the data sets (i.e. RDF) from scratch. I don't have any data at hand. I look for ideas to automatically/programatically generate it.

Comment: Did you read all the Answers to that Question? Note that there are multiple "dayofweek" functions, many of which do not require any RDF data. If you really want to build an RDF dataset comprised of `{ <https://example.com/date/1860-05-08> abc:dayOfWeek "Tuesday" }` triples, you can do it with a looping `CONSTRUCT` + `INSERT` -- but this is a lot of unnecessary data, given the functions will give you the same answer. It's time to think about (and explain) *why* you want this as materialized data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. If I understand, the idea is to calculate the day of the week by programming language and generate RDF accordingly, no? It is good to know there is a way to do it.

Comment: The reason why I would consider having materialise data is as follows (Please correct me, if I am wrong, as I am only thinking theoretically, so the implementation is another question. Indeed, c365 x 4000 is a lot of graphs!):

Comment: 1) as shown above, different types of data (sun rise etc) can be attached. Note that my idea is to create a node with a URI (not a literal with date data type). I have historical meteorological data, diary, newspaper etc to be attached. 2) it would be good if the data can be looked up anytime (not generated on-the-fly by SPARQL each time), so that other users can also refer to. 3) might be faster to use data. In order to generate a visualisation of statistics about what tends to occur on Tuesdays over 100 years, SPARQL would be slow or costly. 4) Wikidata has monthly nodes: Q13067898.